# Get index of minimum element of an Array

Tags: ocaml

I have a function that takes an Array and the minimum value from that Array and returns the position at which that value is located.

```
let findMin a minimum = Array.fold_left (fun pos i -> if a[i] == minimum then i else pos) -1 (Array.range 0 (Array.length a))
```

When I typecheck it I get:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a -> 'a array -> 'a
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

And this part is highlighted:

```
(fun pos i -> if a[i] == minimum then i else pos)
```

So what is the issue?

Comment: Standard library doesn't have a function `Array.range`. Which standard library are you using?

Comment: Note: you could build a *list* of positions in case the element occurs more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem

String `-1` is not parsed as a negative literal, but as two literals `-` and `1`. So OCaml sees your code as follows:

```
Array.fold_left (fun pos i -> if a[i] == minimum then i else pos) -1 (Array.range 0 (Array.length a))
```

lets collapse the expressions, by performing the following substitutions:

```
<fold> ::= Array.fold_left (fun pos i -> if a[i] == minimum then i else pos)
<range> ::= (Array.range 0 (Array.length a))
```

So that now we can see the structure:

```
<fold> "-" "1" <range>
```

Since minus is left associative it first takes an expression:

```
<fold> "-" "1"
```

He is pretty sure that `1` is an `int`. Minus is an operation on integers, so far so good. So the type checker concludes, that the `<fold>` expression should be something from which you can subtract 1, it should be an int. But this is a function - so it outputs a type error.

### Solution

Either parenthesize `-1`, e.g., `(-1)`, or use a prefix minus operator `~-1`.

Answer (score 2):

When I try it, the `Array.fold_left` is also highlighted. The reason is simple: The `-1` must be enclosed in parenthesis (like so: `(-1)`) in order to distinguish the unary from the binary minus. Otherwsie the parser thinks you want to subtract `1` from `Array.fold_left (fun pos i -> if a[i] == minimum then i else pos)`.

Apart from that, you seem to use a non-standard Array library. My test and answer is based on the standard library, so YMMV.